# How can I resize the color thumbnails in Illustrator's swatch panel?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I need to resize the Illustrator's swatch palette icons which are too small on my Mac. How can I do that?

Once I saw a PC with huge icons and I realized that I could do the same on my Mac.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can resize the swatch palette by opening the panel menu:
[image]
And choosing a larger thumbnail view:
[image]
Result:
[image]

Comment: What about other palettes such as the Tool Palette? In my mac it is way too small..

Comment: I don't know how to make the icons on the Tool Palette bigger. I must say that I can see the tools just fine on my 15' non-retina MacBook. Maybe you can just decrease the resolution on your screen in general? Or use glasses ;-)

Comment: glasses, that's it! :p